# reducer is not invoked by reducer redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

The below code dispatches create_event and then call addFlashMessage action

```
export const createEvent = event => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CREATE_EVENT",
      payload: {
        event
      }
    });
    addFlashMessage("Event has been created");
  };
};
```

the addFlashMessage is called at action
But **ADD_FLASH_MESSAGE** is not called

```
export const addFlashMessage = message => {
  console.log("action is invoked");
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_FLASH_MESSAGE",
      payload: {
        message
      }
    });
  };
};
```

This is never being called

```
 case "ADD_FLASH_MESSAGE":
            console.log("action called");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just calling another function from `createEvent` you need to `dispatch` in order to trigger the `redux-thunk` function.

Here is the corrected one.

```
export const createEvent = event => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CREATE_EVENT",
      payload: {
        event
      }
    });
    dispatch(addFlashMessage("Event has been created"));
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `dispatch` the `action` to invoke `addFlashMessage` like following.

```
dispatch({type: "ADD_FLASH_MESSAGE",payload:"Event has been created"});
```

Your code should look like followng.

```
export const createEvent = event => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CREATE_EVENT",
      payload: {
        event
      }
    });
   dispatch({type: "ADD_FLASH_MESSAGE",payload:"Event has been created"});
  };
};
```

Comment: That works but when addFlashMessage("Event has been created"); is called it causes reducer to return dispatch method why that is not happening any clue

Comment: console.log("action is invoked"); i.e action is called but not the reducer

Comment: Ultimately it’s JavaScript.. what you were doing it calling a function and it will work. But redux will not work that way